# split url and get the value

Tags: jquery, url, split

I've a website urls: 
http://web-demo.com/admin/dashboard
http://web-demo.com/web-demo.com/node/14/edit

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var sName = pathArray[0];
var rName;
```

Now, I am able to get sName = 'web-demo.com'. I need 
rName = admin/dashboard;
rName = web-demo.com/node/add/page;
rName = web-demo.com/node/14/edit;

How this is done using jquery? Please help.

Comment: So you're trying to get `rName = web-demo.com/node/14/edit` when the location is `= http://web-demo.com/web-demo.com/node/14/edit`? if so just use window.location.pathname.slice(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var x = "http://web-demo.com/web-demo.com/node/14/edit";
var pathArray = x.split( '/' );
var result = new Array();
alert(pathArray.slice(2).join('/'));
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnQsP/)